# Use Residuals to remove multicollinearity

Tags: econometrics, multicollinearity

This is probably a matter of me not knowing the terminology, but suppose I want to isolate the effect of $X$ on $Y$, and I have some other factor $Z$ that is somewhat correlated with $X$.  So the regression

$Y_i = AX_i + BZ_i + C + E_{i1}$

would potentially have collinearity making $A$ and $B$ imprecise.  I realize I could use an instrumental variable for $Z$, but how about instead first performing a regression

$Z_i = AX_i + C + E_{i2}$

and then just using the residuals $E_{i2}$ instead of $Z_i$, like

$Y_i = AX_i + BE_{i2} + C + E_{i1}$

I've been trying to search for things like "Method of Residuals" but not having any luck finding such technqiues.  I'm sure I've heard about things like this however.  I'm not sure [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225945/multilinear-regression-with-multicollinearity-residual-regression) is exactly the same.

Comment: The search terms you may be looking for are "partial" or "semipartial correlation."

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this technique would get you anywhere. Say you fit the model
$$Z_i = AX_i + C + E_{i2}$$
and calculate your residuals
$$\hat{E}_{i2} = Z_i - (\hat{A}X_i + \hat{C})$$
then your next proposed model

\begin{align*}
Y_i &= A^*X_i+B\hat{E}_{i2} + C^* + E_{i1}\\
&=A^*X_i+B(Z_i - (\hat{A}X_i + \hat{C})) + C^* + E_{i1}\\
&=(A^* - B\hat{A})X_i + BZ_i  - BC + C^* + E_{i1}\\
\end{align*}
which is essentially the same as the first model you wrote out, just with your constants scaled strangely.

If you want to study the effects of $X$ on $Y$, there's no need to get so fancy. First, assess whether $Z$ is actually useful in the model (Partial F-Test, or some likelihood technique). If you choose to include $Z$, determine whether there is significant multicollinearity (VIC). If there is, I'd probably just use ridge regression to stabilize the variance and make your linear coefficient safely interpretable.

Comment: Isn't the point now that I can isolate out $A^*$ from $(A^*-B \hat{A})$?

Comment: I see the intuition behind the idea, but your simultaneous estimation of $(A^* - B\hat{A})$ and $B$ would suffer from the same variance inflation. I can't justify to myself that your estimation of $A^*$ would be stable in the midst of this.